# Display manager not starting KDE. SDDM freezes machine at boot

Tags: kde, lightdm, sddm

This is my first post here so I apologize any inconvenience. After many attempts, I have sucessfully installed Arch and tested some DEs in a virtual machine. I tried GNOME with gdm and it went well. But KDE doesn't start and with sddm it even freezes the boot. The only way out is chroot and disable sddm from starting.

Gdm can start, but after logging in and selecting either x11 or wayland, the result is a black screen (I have both `xorg` and `plasma-wayland-session` installed).
Sddm won't even start. If I type `sddm` on tty the machine freezes. If `systemctl enable sddm` the machine freezes at boot and I can't access tty.
Lightdm if typed on tty nothing happens, just new line. If `systemctl enable lightdm`, it's prompted a message on boot:

> [FAILED] Failed to start Light Display Manager

With the cursor blinking, and I can access tty with ctrl+alt+f2, unlike sddm.
No such issues with GNOME instead.

Comment: I'm currently plagued with SDDM briefly flashing login then the screen blanking. Using tty2, I typed in `sudo systemctl restart sddm.service` and then the login screen restarts and I get the GUI started. Not putting as answer since this is just a hack.